How does Bridge pattern work with Spring Boot?
I am learning about the bridge Pattern using Spring boot and I'm using Chatgpt to help me with the process but I can't understand how it knows when it needs to use EmailSender in EmailNotification and SmsSender in SmsNotification in the example it's giving me. I get confused by the fact that both beans EmailSender and SmsSender are configured to return the Sender type plus EmailNotification and SmsNotification both also have the type Sender in their constructor.
So, how do they know which Sender they both have to use? This is the code I'm trying to understand.
// Sender.java
public interface Sender {
    void send(String message);
}

// EmailSender.java
public class EmailSender implements Sender {
    @Override
    public void send(String message) {
        System.out.println("Sending email: " + message);
    }
}

// SmsSender.java
public class SmsSender implements Sender {
    @Override
    public void send(String message) {
        System.out.println("Sending SMS: " + message);
    }
}

// Notification.java
public abstract class Notification {
    protected Sender sender;

    protected Notification(Sender sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public void notifyUser(String message) {
        sender.send(formatMessage(message));
    }

    protected abstract String formatMessage(String message); // Método abstracto para formatear el mensaje
}

// EmailNotification.java
public class EmailNotification extends Notification {
    public EmailNotification(Sender sender) {
        super(sender);
    }

    @Override
    protected String formatMessage(String message) {
        return "Email Notification: " + message;
    }
}

// SmsNotification.java
public class SmsNotification extends Notification {
    public SmsNotification(Sender sender) {
        super(sender);
    }

    @Override
    protected String formatMessage(String message) {
        return "SMS Notification: " + message;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Sender emailSender() {
        return new EmailSender();
    }

    @Bean
    public Sender smsSender() {
        return new SmsSender();
    }

    @Bean
    public Notification emailNotification(Sender emailSender) {
        return new EmailNotification(emailSender);
    }

    @Bean
    public Notification smsNotification(Sender smsSender) {
        return new SmsNotification(smsSender);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/notifications")
public class NotificationController {

    private final Notification emailNotification;
    private final Notification smsNotification;

    @Autowired
    public NotificationController(Notification emailNotification, Notification smsNotification) {
        this.emailNotification = emailNotification;
        this.smsNotification = smsNotification;
    }

    @GetMapping("/email")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendEmailNotification() {
        emailNotification.notifyUser("Hello via Email!");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Email notification sent!");
    }

    @GetMapping("/sms")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendSmsNotification() {
        smsNotification.notifyUser("Hello via SMS!");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("SMS notification sent!");
    }
}

I'm confused about how it knows that EmailNotification uses EmailSender in the AppConfig and same for SmsNotification since the method signatures are the same even if the return type is not. Can't understand how it's relating each Notification to each Sender. Is it because of the params names "emailSender" and "smsSender" in "emailNotification" and "smsNotification" beans definitions?
I think I'm not understanding something about the dependencies injections with Spring since something similar happens in the Controller constructor. How does it know which implementation to use for both EmailNotification and SmsNotification since both types are Notification? I have the feeling it's because of the params names which are the same that the ones defined in the AppConfig. Am I right?
Thanks!

Spring first matches on type and then on name.  You have a bean named emailSender.  You can override this with @Qualifier but by default the qualifier is the bean name.  You can also test this out by changing the parameter names, you'll likely get a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

So my assumption was right and in EmailNotification it uses EmailSender because the param name is emailSender and the same for the constructor in the controller? @lane.maxwell

Yep, your intuition has served you well!

Okay this was happening because as I assumed and as @lane.maxwell confirmed, the beans names are the "method names". So I used @Qualifier to remove this ambiguity:
@Configuration
public class NotificationConfig {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("emailSender")
    public Sender emailSender() {
        return new EmailSender();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("smsSender")
    public Sender smsSender() {
        return new SmsSender();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("emailNotification")
    public Notification emailNotification(@Qualifier("emailSender") Sender emailSender) {
        return new EmailNotification(emailSender);
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("smsNotification")
    public Notification smsNotification(@Qualifier("smsSender") Sender smsSender) {
        return new SmsNotification(smsSender);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/notifications")
public class NotificationController {

    private final Notification emailNotification;
    private final Notification smsNotification;

    @Autowired
    public NotificationController(
        @Qualifier("emailNotification") Notification emailNotification,
        @Qualifier("smsNotification") Notification smsNotification) {
        this.emailNotification = emailNotification;
        this.smsNotification = smsNotification;
    }

    @GetMapping("/email")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendEmailNotification() {
        emailNotification.notifyUser("Hello via Email!");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Email notification sent!");
    }

    @GetMapping("/sms")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendSmsNotification() {
        smsNotification.notifyUser("Hello via SMS!");
        return ResponseEntity.ok("SMS notification sent!");
    }
}


Good start - learning DP, but I believe, it is also important to do everything right, even it might be hard to do everything right from the very beginning.

SOLID

Putting all configurations into one class is breaking SRP, you can just annotate all implementations by @Component and maybe using annotation would be more clear than the @Qualifier.
Command DP would be for your use-case better - Open-Closed Principle.



From the very beginning of OOP programming, try this test - remove a feature,
or an implementation without modifying anything.
If you can do that, you did choose the right DP.
Your example with Command DP would be, that you will have parameterized interface Sender, and you will have just one dependency in all your other classes, so every time new implementation come, you will not change existing classes.
